# Wordpress term query page pagination not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have displayed all the terms in one page in WordPress. Everything is working fine. But the pagination is not working properly. I tried many ways. Didn't work. How do I fix it? Any ideas please? Below is my code ...

```
 <?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $tax_args = array(
      'paged' => $paged,
      'taxonomy' => 'property-land',
      'order'     => 'DESC',
      'number'  => 12,
      'hide_empty' => 0
    );
    $term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $tax_args );
      
    foreach ( $term_query->get_terms() as $term ) :
      $count_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term->slug,
            ),
        )
    ); ?>

    <h2><a href='<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id ) ); ?>'><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h2>
    
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    endforeach; ?>
    
    <?php //$total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
    $total_pages = $term_query->query_vars['number'];


      if ( $total_pages > 1){
          $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
          echo paginate_links(array(
              'base' => get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%',
              'format' => '/page/%#%',
              'current' => $current_page,
              'total' => $total_pages,
              'prev_text'    => __( '«' ),
              'next_text'    => __( '»' ),
          ));
      } ?>
```

Comment: Not working properly or not working completely?

Comment: Not working properly

Comment: *"Didn't work"*, *"Not working properly"*, What's not working? Can you explain more? If it's hard to explain, you could, at least, provide some screenshot(s). Do you get any warning(s)/error(s)?